# Can;t show task pane of excel add-in tutorial

Tags: excel, office-addins

I am learning Office add-n and have just been practicing to make a button in excel. I can't show the new button in the excel ribbon even copy and run the complete add-in project from GitHub. Can anyone help?

Best regards

Tuan

Comment: duplicate of [Command button does not appear in ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125090/developer-add-in-does-not-appear-on-the-ribbon-office-word-react-macos)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the following applies:

1. Office Desktop products must be versioned 16 or higher
2. In your XML, you need to make sure that you are making all HttpS requests. It must be secure
3. Make sure that you are not missing any closing tag `/>`.

Also you should be able to see the changes on 365 since they are using the latest version.