# Developer Add-in does not appear on the ribbon - office word react, MacOs

Tags: macos, reactjs, integration, office-addins

I have followed every step in this guid given from microsoft. However, I'm using word instead fo excel ( I did try the excel also) and i'm not getting the command add-in in the ribbon. Though I can see the add-in pane. Again I did not change anything. So there is no point sharing any code.

react guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react

any idea why i'm not seeing the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that i had to update my office to the latest version (16 or higher)

[Office Sample Git Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeDrH.png)